# XDocument.Load generates error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-xml

I am getting the following error:

```
"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
```

Here is the WEB APIpartial code:

```
//POST api/RunningValue_Import
public object PostRunningValue(HttpRequestMessage xml)
{
    try
    {
        #region Retrieve XML string and Create XDocument

        //the method below generates the same error:
        //string tempXmlString = xml.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        //TextReader tr = new StringReader(tempXmlString);
        //XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result); //<=== ERROR!

        #endregion
```

jQuery:

```
var inputText = inputText.replace(/ /g, ''); //eliminate spaces
inputText = inputText.replace(/\"/g, '\\"'); //escape double quotes

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: reqUrl,
    data: inputText,
    datatype: "text",
    contentType: "text/xml"
});
```

inputText variable content:

```
inputText = "\\\"<?xmlversion=\\\"1.0\\\"encoding=\\\"utf-8\\\"standalone=\\\"yes\\\"?>\n<server>\n<networkAdapters>\n<networkAdapterid=\\\"3d9c0d9d-d353-4d78-b034-b29f2dd824a0\\\">\n</networkAdapter>\n</networkAdapter>\n</server>\\\""
```

Original XMl string passed:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<server>
  <networkAdapters>
    <networkAdapter id="3d9c0d9d-d353-4d78-b034-b29f2dd824a0">
    </networkAdapter>
  </networkAdapter>
</server>"
```

Comment: You actually pass quotes around XML data? You shouldn't.

Comment: oh gee thanks! now I am getting: "the '=' character hexadecimal value 0x3d cannot be included in a name" .... researching on that now...

Comment: You shouldn't put \n characters in your XML either. The server doesn't care if it looks pretty.

Comment: it is complaining about a "=" ; I removed the /n as well :-)

Comment: @Max feel free to answer your own question and accept it.  It might help someone in the future who has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all spaces is causing you a problem. If I un-escape quotes and slashes you will see that it is not valid XML:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"standalone="yes"?><server><networkAdapters><networkAdapterid="3d9c0d9d-d353-4d78-b034-b29f2dd824a0"></networkAdapter></networkAdapter></server>
```

If you try to format it for readability it looks like this:

```
<!-- This declaration is invalid without spacing -->
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"standalone="yes"?>
<server>
    <networkAdapters>
        <!-- This should read "networkAdapter id" not "networkAdapterid" -->
        <networkAdapterid="3d9c0d9d-d353-4d78-b034-b29f2dd824a0"></networkAdapter>
    <!-- This should be a closing bracket for networkAdapters, not networkAdapter -->
    </networkAdapter>
</server>
```

Comment: Lack of spaces or new lines between elements does not matter at all.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it depends on the parser. Most parsers require whitespace in the document declaration. `<?xmlversion` is not the same as '<?xml version`. But I did find another basic problem with it and I'm editing my answer right now.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realized the space between `?xml` and `version is gone. You're right, this one is definitely necessary to make it valid XML.